# Do I need to unset loop variables in PHP?

Tags: php, garbage-collection

Lets say I have a loop that re-assigns an array with database-returned values as so:

```
while( $row = $query -> fetch_assoc() ){
    $arr[] = $row;
}
```

Do I need to unset the variables from this loop if I am no longer using them? ie:

```
unset($query);
unset($row);
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of this? Do I need to bother unsetting these variables? I have cronjobs running on this server that are very resource intensive and I want to keep my scripts as low-memory as possible.

Comment: You don't need to. [PHP automatically does it for you](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php).

Comment: You'd get more  efficiency if you could "handle" whatever you need to do with the database results in your while loop rather than building a large array in memory.... building that array is more resource intensive than the existence of $query and $row variables